# How to manipulate a tabbed view in Titanium and add SQLite content?

Tags: javascript, android, xml, sqlite, titanium

> **The Overview**

I am fairly new to Titanium and I decided to finally start working with SQLite and some new UI features. I opted for the TabGroup as I felt that would be the best option. However I'm having a few issues. I am trying to simply get some quotes which have been inserted to a table (tested and working, I alerted them out and it worked) and I wish to display them out in the wiseWords tab, so the user can view them.

> **The Code**

**index.xml**

```
<Alloy id="index">
    <TabGroup>
        <Require src="home"></Require>
        <Require src="wiseWords"></Require>
        <Require src="settings"></Require>
    </TabGroup>
</Alloy>
```

**index.js**

```
$.index.open(); 

/** Create and populate the wise words table. **/
Alloy.Globals.createRequiredTables();

var selectWiseWordsSQL = "SELECT * FROM wise_words";
var selectWiseWords = Titanium.App.db.execute(selectWiseWordsSQL);

while (selectWiseWords.isValidRow()) {
    /** Create labels for each quote. **/
    var addQuote = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        text : selectWiseWords.fieldByName("saying") + " - " + selectWiseWords.fieldByName("quoted_by"),
    });

    /** Add quote to window (available in wiseWords.xml). **/
    $.wiseWordsWindow.add(addQuote);

    selectWiseWords.next();
}
selectWiseWords.close();
```

**wiseWords.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <Tab id="wiseWordsTab" title="Wise Words">
        <Window id="wiseWordsWindow" class="container" title="Wise Words">  
        </Window>
    </Tab>
</Alloy>
```

> **The Error(s)**

*Runetime Error*

*Location: alloy/controllers/index.js*

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'add' of undefined.*

*Source: $.wiseWordsWindow.add(addQuote);*

> **To Clarify...**

I understand what the error means, but don't understand why it is being thrown.

1. Why can't I access the view for wiseWords.xml in index.js even though wiseWords is referenced in index.xml through the `<Require>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Clarification**

You are calling **add** method of window with id wiseWordsWindow. but according to your code you are using this controller in you index.xml file using require. so you are not able to directly access the elements of wiseWords controller. so you can try to create method in wiseWords controller which can be accessed from index file and then add child to the wiseWordsWindow. there are two ways you can do this.

### Solution 1

> **The Code**

**index.xml** (in this file give **id** to wiseWords)

```
<Alloy id="index">
    <TabGroup>
        <Require src="home"></Require>
        <Require id="wiseWordsWin" src="wiseWords"></Require>
        <Require src="settings"></Require>
    </TabGroup>
</Alloy>
```

**index.js** (in this file change method call for **add** to the method we will be creating in our wiseWords controller)

change ***$.wiseWordsWindow.add(addQuote);*** line to following.

```
$.wiseWordsWin.addQuote(addQuote);
```

**updated code for index.js**

```
/** Create and populate the wise words table. **/
Alloy.Globals.createRequiredTables();

var selectWiseWordsSQL = "SELECT * FROM wise_words";
var selectWiseWords = Titanium.App.db.execute(selectWiseWordsSQL);

while (selectWiseWords.isValidRow()) {
    /** Create labels for each quote. **/
    var addQuote = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        text : selectWiseWords.fieldByName("saying") + " - " + selectWiseWords.fieldByName("quoted_by"),
    });

    /** Add quote to window (available in wiseWords.xml). **/
    $.wiseWordsWin.addQuote(addQuote);

    selectWiseWords.next();
}
selectWiseWords.close();
$.index.open();
```

**wiseWords  (keep this file as it is)**

**wiseWords.js** (add **addQuote** method in this controller and assign it to our controller)

```
function addQuote(_quote){
    $.wiseWordsWindow.add(_quote);
}
exports.addQuote = addQuote;
```

### Solution 2

In this Solution code for index.xml will be same as first solution.
changes will be in index.js and wiseWords.js.

> **The Code**

**wiseWords.js** (add following lines to this file)

```
exports.myWiseWordsWin = $.wiseWordsWindow;
```

**index.js** (now we can access our wiseWordsWindow from index file using created reference for out window)

change ***$.wiseWordsWindow.add(addQuote);*** line to following.

```
$.wiseWordsWin.myWiseWordsWin.add(addQuote);
```

**updated code for index.js**

```
/** Create and populate the wise words table. **/
Alloy.Globals.createRequiredTables();

var selectWiseWordsSQL = "SELECT * FROM wise_words";
var selectWiseWords = Titanium.App.db.execute(selectWiseWordsSQL);

while (selectWiseWords.isValidRow()) {
    /** Create labels for each quote. **/
    var addQuote = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        text : selectWiseWords.fieldByName("saying") + " - " + selectWiseWords.fieldByName("quoted_by"),
    });

    /** Add quote to window (available in wiseWords.xml). **/
    $.wiseWordsWin.myWiseWordsWin.add(addQuote);
    selectWiseWords.next();
}
selectWiseWords.close();
$.index.open();
```

Hope this will help

Comment: In your first solution you say I should do `$.wiseWordsWin...` but I don't understand how that works. Doesn't that ID refer to the whole view and not just the right `<Window>` tag I have in wiseWords.xml? I want to add any dynamically added tags in the `<Window>` tag.

Comment: i had updated the solution with more explanation. you can refer to that, let me know if still there is any confusion. i'll explain.

Comment: New error, `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Controller> has no method 'addQuote'. Source $.wiseWordsView.addQuote(addQuote);` this happened when I tried solution 1.

Comment: The issue I think is that the controllers index.js and wiseWords are not connected so it fails. Any ideas how to connect controllers?

Comment: Yes. I tried that and an error occurred where it couldn't find the variable we created in wiseWords.js.

Comment: function addQuote(_quote){
    $.wiseWordsWindow.add(_quote);
}
$.wiseWordsTab.addQuote = addQuote;

hey in first solution change $.wiseWordsTab.addQuote = addQuote; line in wiseWords.js file to exports.addQuote = addQuote; and you will be able to run the application.

Comment: and in second solution also you can change $.wiseWordsTab.myWiseWordsWin = $.wiseWordsWindow; to exports.myWiseWordsWin = $.wiseWordsWindow; and it should work fine.

Comment: let me know if this solutions work, i'll update the answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Marked as correct answer. I tried solution 1.